# making space between two hyperlinks in div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have two hyperlinks in div tag, I want to make a space between these two hyperlink

how should I do that?

```css
.btn-filter {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 40px !important;
  width: 110px !important;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  margin-left: 10px !important;
}

.btn-filter>a {
  color: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-inline">
  <div class="btn-filter  w-50">
    <a asp-controller="" asp-action="" class="">0-2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-filter w-50">
    <a asp-controller="" asp-action="" class="">3-5 </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, surprised   justify-content: space-between;  did not do it

Comment: display: flex goes on a parent element, not the children

Comment: I added a fiddle for you, but there is some redundant code, and the w-50 is not helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way of doing it. I removed w-50 for instance, and the table-cell part. Without knowing your specific case, It's hard for me to show you exactly what you want other than just the addition of margin within the parent div, but hopefully you'll understand how it works and how some bootstrap classes are not always to be used (50% width on two items makes up to 100%, the space inbetween that can be utilized is thereby 0%.)
See example below.

```css
.btn-filter {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width:100px;
  float:left;
  margin-right:50px

}

.btn-filter>a {
  color: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div>
  <div class="btn-filter">
    <a asp-controller="" asp-action="" class="">0-2</a>
  </div>

  <div class="btn-filter">
    <a asp-controller="" asp-action="" class="">3-5 </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not flex?...

Comment: I usually personally only use flex if the box itself needs to become bigger or smaller depending on window size. In op's request, he has set the width to an finite number, so I simply added margin on an float. But as you say, flex can be used and I agree that if I had to stick with either flex or float for the rest of my life, it would be flex.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a column based approach where you add left/right margin to your children and then use negative spacing on your parent to keep the left alignment:

```
.btn-filter-wrap {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.btn-filter-inner {
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.btn-filter {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

You would then add this `.btn-filter-wrap` class to your `.d-inline` element and then REMOVE this `.d-inline` class. The inline display property is intended more for text and images. If you want to change the spacing, just make sure your updates are consistent between the parent and child margin properties.

EDIT:

I am now noticing that you are also attempting to use "display: table-cell" on your child items. Remove that and stick to flex. It would be best to update everything to use `<table>` elements if you want to display a table.

```css
.btn-filter-wrap {
/* Potential side gutter spacing */
/*
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
*/

  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn-filter-inner {
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right: -10px;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn-filter {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  
  height: 40px;
  width: 110px;
}

.btn-filter>a {
  color: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="btn-filter-wrap">
  <div class="btn-filter-inner">
    <div class="btn-filter">
      <a asp-controller="" asp-action="" class="">0-2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-filter">
      <a asp-controller="" asp-action="" class="">3-5 </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```